# Proyecto react-native no funciona bien el new Date ()

Tags: react-native, momentjs

Buenas tardes estoy usando la librería moment.js en un proyecto de react, pero no logro que me lleve bien la hora a la base de datos, con un substract -5, la muestra bien en el dispositivo pero a base de datos, siempre me guarda la hora con 5 horas demás. Alguien me puede dar una luz de esto porque sucede, ya revise en foros y varias paginas y parece que todo el código esta bien , pero sigue llevándome el error

Comment: ¿Tal vez sea que tu servidor está en una zona horaria que difiere por 5 horas de tu hora local? En ese caso los datos estarían bien, te recomiendo manejar los tiempos con UTC para evitar este tipo de problemas. O podría ser que tu servidor funcione con UTC y tu le estás pasando el tiempo local.

Comment: El servidor se encuentra en la hora adecuada, la base de datos interactua con otra aplicación creada de jquery y funciona sin este problema. Me explicas lo de UTC como hago para pasarle el tiempo local si funciona con UTC

Comment: Te explico con un ejemplo por medio de una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente se manejan todos los tiempos de tu backend en UTC y los conviertes en el frontend exclusivamente para la visualización/interacción del usuario (de acuerdo a su zona horaria).

De esta manera no tienes que preocuparte por manejar diferentes zonas horarias, mira por ejemplo que estás diciendo:

> con un substract -5, la muestra bien en el dispositivo pero a base de datos, siempre me guarda la hora con 5 horas demás

Esto significa que dependiendo de donde sea el usuario tienes que hacer una modificación **manual** de la hora y tendrías que manejar cada caso por separado por medio de una implementación diferente en tú código. Esto es sumamente complicado. Apostaría a que el problema que tienes es porque tu zona horaria es UTC-5, es decir que ahorita estás en México, Chile, Ecuador, Colombia, Panamá o Perú.

La base de datos debe de guardar fechas con una referencia que funcione para cualquier lugar del mundo, esto para poder ser utilizada por cualquier usuario, sin importar desde donde se conecten, entonces guarda los tiempos con formato UTC... Que corresponde 5 horas más con respecto a donde estás.

Mira este ejemplo:

```js
function obtenerDatoDesdeBD() {
  return {
    timestamp: "2020-12-14T18:07:16.452Z",
    accion: "compra",
    usuario: "franacuna"
  }
}


//Vamos a simular que obtenemos un dato llamado compra desde la base de datos:
const compra = obtenerDatoDesdeBD();

//Vamos a guardar un objeto tipo Date para manejar la fecha de la compra
const tiempoDeCompra = new Date(compra.timestamp);

//Yo soy de Costa Rica por lo tanto, la base de datos registro que hice mi compra a las 6 de la tarde. 
//Cuando en realidad la hice a medio dia porque mi zona horaria es UTC-6. 
//En tu caso visto desde tu país yo hice el pago a la 1 de la tarde.

//Supongamos que voy a mostrarle al cliente (por medio de un console.log) 
//la hora a la que realizo su pago, asi:
console.log("Su compra fue realizada en la fecha ", tiempoDeCompra);

//El cliente estaría confundido porque esto no correspondería a la hora local a la cual realizó el pago, 
//me podría ver tentado a simplemente restarle las 6 horas al timestamp... 
//Pero sería un problema para un usuario que sea por ejemplo de tu país.

//Por lo tanto si quieres mostrar el dato o dejar que el usuario lo manipule,
//lo mejor es dejar que el explorador/dispositivo lo convierta a la fecha local
console.log("Su compra fue realizada en la fecha: ", tiempoDeCompra.toLocaleString())
```

En este caso utilizé `toLocaleString()` y de esta manera no importa de donde se acceda el dato, siempre será correcto... Yo lo visualizo como:

```
Su compra fue realizada en la fecha:  12/14/2020, 12:07:16
```

Y tú lo debes de ver cómo:

```
Su compra fue realizada en la fecha:  12/14/2020, 13:07:16
```

Y por eso en la base de datos está guardado cómo:

```
Su compra fue realizada en la fecha:  12/14/2020, 18:07:16
```

La hora de tu base de datos está bien, las horas deben de guardarse en UTC para tener un punto de referencia que podamos convertir luego a horas locales tu código también debe de estar bien. Para tu base de datos la hora actual está adelantada por 5 horas.