# Error en una consulta a la base de datos en NodeJs

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express, sql

no se si el titulo es adecuado porque mas que un error tengo un comportamiento extraño en mi aplicación **NodeJs** con **express** y **Postgresql**

Para empezar realizo un *insert* a mi DB en un campo llamado *fecha* del tipo *timestamp* de la siguiente forma:

```
var newDate = new Date();
// agrego 5 minutos a la fecha y hora actuales
newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() + 5);
// convierto a string el resultado
var string_newDate = newDate.toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')
console.log('tipo:', typeof(string_newDate), ', valor:',string_newDate);
//: tipo: string  valor: 2020-12-14 20:17:53
// guardo en la DB:
database.query('INSERT INTO usuario(fecha) VALUES ($1)', [string_newDate])
```

Al hacer una consulta a la DB por terminal me muestra exactamente ese valor:

```
Select fecha from usuario where id = 1;
// obtengo: 2020-12-14 20:17:53
```

El problema surge cuando la consulta la hago desde mi aplicacion nodejs:

```
const result = await database.query('SELECT fecha from usuario where id = 1');
...
console.log('tipo:', typeof(result.rows.fecha), 'valor:', typeof(result.rows.fecha))
// obtengo esta fecha:
// tipo: object valor: 2020-12-15T01:17:53.000Z
```

La fecha que obtengo al hacer la consulta con nodejs es *2020-12-15T01:17:53.000Z* no lo que tengo almacenado en mi base de datos que es *2020-12-14 20:17:53*.

Como dato adicional sin importar que fecha guarde, la fecha que obtengo al hacer la consulta con nodejs es **5 horas por encima de la que guardé**, como en este caso.

Agradezco cualquier colaboración con este problema, estaré aquí todo el tiempo que haga falta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces el query tu base de datos te devuelve la fecha usando UTC, curiosamente se parece al problema descrito en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414397/proyecto-react-native-no-funciona-bien-el-new-date) de la mañana.

Mira que lo que obtienes (partiendo del último pedazo de código en tu pregunta) es:

> 2020-12-15T01:17:53.000Z

Esta es una *ISO string* y la `Z` al final indica que es tiempo **UTC**, por lo tanto es equivalente a `2020-12-14 20:17:53` (desde tu punto de vista/horario local).

Puedes solucionar esto haciendo cambiandola al formato de la fecha local:

```
const result = await database.query('SELECT fecha from usuario where id = 1');
...
const fecha = new Date(result.rows.fecha);
console.log('tipo:', typeof(Date.toLocaleString()), 'valor:', typeof(Date.toLocaleString()))
```

En resumen... No estás viendo fechas diferentes, lo que pasa es que estás viendo la misma fecha en formatos distintos (UTC y UTC-5).

Comment: Oh por dios, es justamente lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias por la respuesta amigo es simple y concisa. Debo admitir que quedé como un novato porque desconocía todo este tema del formato de fechas. Prometo documentarme más.